# Is it possible to make a proxy between IDE and language server?

Tags: language-server-protocol

Say, I want to slightly change the behavior of some language.

Can this be done? Has it been done before?

UPD: Typescript has very limited possibilites to work with property names (for example you can not with the help of typescript create a propname that is derived from another one, e.g. uppercased or with a prefix prepended), whereas Javascript (which is what Typescript compiles to) is very flexible. So I wanted with the help of LSP to modify some of the Typescript's LSP messages that carry autocompletion options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but how to do that is operating system specific. From the compiler's point of view, the proxy would appear as your IDE. [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) is a *network protocol*

> I want to slightly change the behavior of some language.

So you want to change the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of some language (and you don't tell which). Then LSP is not the best place to do so.

For example, in some simple cases, with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), writing your GCC [plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) is more appropriate.

In most cases, changing the "behavior" is really changing the language itself. Then you might need to make your own implementation of that language. Sometimes, you might patch an existing free software implementation of the original languages. In other cases, you'll need to make your language implementation by yourself. Then read the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) and consider compiling or transpiling [to C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) your language in your language implementation. Be sure to specify it on paper first.

Don't confuse a programming language (which is a *specification*, generally written in English - perhaps with some formalization in some specific notation, e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for C11, [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/) for Scheme) with its implementation (which is a software). Read Scott's [*Programming Language Pragmatics*](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/).

Don't confuse an IDE with a language implementation. For example, all C or C++ compilers I know about don't have any IDE and are command line programs (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), etc...), and most of them don't even know about LSP. The IDE might *start* the C++ compiler, but it is not a compiler. You can code (in C, C++, Java, C#, Ocaml, ....) with a plain [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (even a simple language-agnostic one such as Notepad on Windows, or Leafpad or nano on Linux).

Most programming languages are defining source programs as a set of "translation units", practically of "source files", each being a sequence of characters with some complex syntax and semantics. How these source files are created is outside of the scope of the programming language specification (you could use editors, you could write your own generators for these source files, ....)

LSP is a proposal for a protocol between "IDE"s and language implementations.

Notice that autocompletion (mentioned in your comment) is not a feature of the programming language (and is not part of the semantics of C or C++). It might be a feature of some IDEs (not all of them). It could be done in a language neutral way (e.g. in [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)).

Comment: Hi Basile, Thank you very much! Well it's not the semantics, I want just to change some property names in the autocompletion.

Comment: But autocompletion is *not* a property of the *language*. It is simply a feature of some IDE.

Comment: Yes, But I thought autocompletion is based on what LS sends to IDE via LSP. But I am in my beginning of this LSP journey, so I might got it wrong. Anyway huuuge thanks for your very detailed answer! It's a good food for my brain and it provides good directions of where I should go!

Comment: I've added an update so you can understand my point better, hopefully. But all of you answer is still very valuable.